# How to change push notification sound?

Tags: php, ios, laravel

I am using laravel 5 and php and for push notification 
    github link(https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification).
    What should I do to change push notification sound ?

Answer (score 2):

When you prepare your `message` to send you have a field `sound`. You can edit there to change the sound.

```
$message = PushNotification::Message('Message Text',array(
    'badge' => 1,
    'sound' => 'example.aiff', // EDIT THIS filename

    'actionLocKey' => 'Action button title!',
    'locKey' => 'localized key',
    'locArgs' => array(
        'localized args',
        'localized args',
    ),
    'launchImage' => 'image.jpg',

    'custom' => array('custom data' => array(
        'we' => 'want', 'send to app'
    ))
));
```

This example is from the link you provided.

Comment: yup i tried to but didnot work. I stored sound clip and gave the path in sound field but there was no change